# ReadConsoleInputA throws an Access Violation

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86, masm

I am trying to learn how to use the windows api (instead of just using C calls, irvine32 or masm32) And are running into issues with ReadConsoleInputA (WriteConsoleA works fine).

Also, I don't get why in the PROC prototype for the function, most examples append either an A or a W at the end of ReadConsoleInput/WriteConsole, can you explain why?

```
.data
consoleOutHandle dd ?
consoleInHandle dd ?
bufferlen dd ?
buffer db ?
bufferSize DWORD ?
message db "Enter a number:", 0
lmessage equ $-message


.code
main PROC

    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov consoleOutHandle, eax

    invoke ReadConsoleInputA, consoleOutHandle, offset buffer, 128, bufferSize
main endp
end main
```

It throws: Access violation writing location 0x00000004.

Following the advice from Michael Petch, I have this code now:

```
.data
consoleOutHandle dd ?
consoleInHandle dd ?
byteswritten dd ?
bufferlen dd ?
buffer db 128 DUP(?)
bufferSize dd ?
message db "Enter a number:", 0
lmessage equ $-message


.code
main PROC
    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    mov consoleInHandle, eax
    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov consoleOutHandle, eax
    mov eax, lmessage
    invoke WriteConsoleA, consoleOutHandle, offset message, eax, bytesWritten, 0

    invoke ReadConsoleInputA, consoleInHandle, offset buffer, 128, offset bufferSize
main endp
end main
```

And now it throws "triggered a breakpoint".

Disassembly:

```
invoke ReadConsoleInputA, consoleInHandle, offset buffer, 128, offset bufferSize
00E71066  push        offset bufferSize (0E74090h)  
00E7106B  push        80h  
00E71070  push        offset buffer (0E74010h)  
00E71075  push        dword ptr [consoleInHandle (0E74004h)]  
00E7107B  call        _ReadConsoleInputA@16 (0E7100Ah)  
--- No source file -------------------------------------------------------------
00E71080  int         3    **---> Breakpoint here**
00E71081  int         3
```

Comment: Did that, but now it "triggered a breakpoint".  I have tried your suggestions in the past, I keep getting either a "triggered breakpoint" or an "access violation".

Comment: Yes, I have updated the original post with your recommendations.  Thank you for the link (A&W)

Comment: Sorry, reverted it back to the original.  This is the dissasembly:

000E103C  push        offset bufferSize (0E408Ch)  
000E1041  push        80h  
000E1046  push        offset buffer (0E400Ch)  
000E104B  push        dword ptr [consoleOutHandle (0E4000h)]  
000E1051  call        _ReadConsoleInputA@16 (0E100Ah)  
--- No source file -------------------------------------------------------------
000E1056  int         3 <- breakpoint here

Comment: @MichaelPetch: That's a bit too strong.  Fixing an obvious and uninteresting bug like failure to reserve enough space seems like a good idea when it's not the whole problem.  It's come up in plenty of SO questions before.  I'd suggest the OP should at least add a 2nd code block with the changed version (and one with the disassembly because comments don't have formatting).

Comment: But anyway, now the bug is just a missing `ret` leading to falling off the end of the function into the `int3` padding that MASM and/or the linker put between functions exactly for this reason.  There are at least a couple existing questions about falling off the end of functions, but maybe none with MASM where it hits an `int3`.

Comment: Thank you, I have followed your recommendations and appended that information to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked what the `A` and `W` suffix on the end of the WinAPI functions are for. Functions ending with `A` denote `A`nsi, and functions ending with `W` are `W`ide. Microsoft documents them this way:

> Unicode and ANSI Functions
>   When Microsoft introduced Unicode support to Windows, it eased the transition by providing two parallel sets of APIs, one for ANSI strings and the other for Unicode strings. For example, there are two functions to set the text of a window's title bar:
>
> - `SetWindowTextA` takes an ANSI string.
> - `SetWindowTextW` takes a Unicode string.

---

In the first version of the code

- You don't allocate space necessary for `buffer`. You had:

  ```
  buffer db ?
  ```

  That allocated a single byte to the buffer. It should have been:

  ```
  buffer db 128 DUP(?)
  ```
- You used `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` instead of `STD_INPUT_HANDLE`
- The last parameter to `ReadConsoleInputA` is a pointer to a DWORD that will return the number of events read. Changing the variable name `bufferSize` might make the code more readable. From the [ReadConsoleInputA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) documentation:

  > ```
  > BOOL WINAPI ReadConsoleInput(
  >  _In_  HANDLE        hConsoleInput,
  >  _Out_ PINPUT_RECORD lpBuffer,
  >  _In_  DWORD         nLength,
  >  _Out_ LPDWORD       lpNumberOfEventsRead
  > );
  > ```
- If you are reading just the keyboard you should be using [`ReadConsoleA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole) as `ReadConsoleInputA` will process keyboard and mouse events and may prematurely return before your string is read. `ReadConsoleA` takes one extra parameter and you can set it to NULL:

  > ```
  > BOOL WINAPI ReadConsole(
  >  _In_     HANDLE  hConsoleInput,
  >  _Out_    LPVOID  lpBuffer,
  >  _In_     DWORD   nNumberOfCharsToRead,
  >  _Out_    LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsRead,
  >  _In_opt_ LPVOID  pInputControl
  > );
  > ```
- To exit the program you need to invoke `ExitProcess` .

---

In the second version of the code

- Your code does:

  ```
  invoke WriteConsoleA, consoleOutHandle, offset message, eax, bytesWritten, 0
  ```

  `bytesWritten` needs to be a pointer because that is an output parameter. From [WriteConsoleA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) documentation:

  > ```
  > BOOL WINAPI WriteConsole(
  >  _In_             HANDLE  hConsoleOutput,
  >  _In_       const VOID    *lpBuffer,
  >  _In_             DWORD   nNumberOfCharsToWrite,
  >  _Out_            LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsWritten,
  >  _Reserved_       LPVOID  lpReserved
  >  );
  > ```

---

A version of the code that uses `ReadConsoleA` instead of `ReadConsoleInputA` based on your second code example could look like:

```
.data
consoleOutHandle dd ?
consoleInHandle dd ?
bytesWritten dd ?
bufferlen dd ?
buffer db 128 DUP(?)
numEvents dd ?
message db "Enter a number:", 0
lmessage equ $-message

.code
main PROC
    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    mov consoleInHandle, eax
    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov consoleOutHandle, eax
    mov eax, lmessage
    invoke WriteConsoleA, consoleOutHandle, offset message, eax, offset bytesWritten, 0

    invoke ReadConsoleA, consoleInHandle, offset buffer, 128, offset numEvents, 0
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp
end main
```

This code can be cleaned up a bit by using MASM's `sizeof` operator. The code could be written as:

```
.data
consoleOutHandle dd ?
consoleInHandle dd ?
buffer db 128 DUP(?)
bytesWritten dd ?
numEvents dd ?
message db "Enter a number:", 0

.code
main PROC
    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    mov consoleInHandle, eax
    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov consoleOutHandle, eax
    invoke WriteConsoleA, consoleOutHandle, offset message, sizeof message, offset bytesWritten, 0
    invoke ReadConsoleA, consoleInHandle, offset buffer, sizeof buffer, offset numEvents, 0
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Oh god, THANK YOU!  Indeed, the ReadConsoleInput returns after the first keystroke.  This works perfectly.